# Express error - TypeError: express.Router is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm going through [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdNuw0mk3xY&index=17&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBMdkKFn3HasZnnAqVjzHn_) tutorial by thenewboston using Express, EJS, and Node. My code is almost exactly set up like his, except at the end using app.listen instead of module.exports = send.

I get the following error when I try to run my node program:

```
var router = express.Router();
                 ^
TypeError: express.Router is not a function
```

Here is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncommet after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward error to handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

and my index.js file is:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I've done a similar tutorial before, and didn't have this problem arise. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you install `express`? Check your `package.json`.

Comment: Yes. It's there. The program ran just fine when the index.js file was just: exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' })
};

Comment: @crash springfield, did you ever get an answer to this question. I have the same problem.

Comment: I've tried to run you program except I removed almost all other packages except express, path, and ejs. The server runs fine. Have you tried  reinstalling express? My express version is 4.16.2

Answer (score 0):

Working with EcmaScript modules (files extension .mjs) and node version `v12.16.1` and with  `"express": "~4.16.1"` I faced the same error.

In my case, since it was used `import * as express from 'express';` instead of require, I had to change import statement to `import express from 'express';` and the issue was solved.

Answer (score -2):

Try this - obtained from sample code from express/lib/application.js.

`var http = require('http')
       ,https = require('https)
       ,express = require('express')`

`var app = express()`

Worked for me.  Most likely, only one or the other of http / https is required.